# Chrome Extension to record user events in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, chrome

Is there any Google Chrome Extensions that record the user doing events and display as a template of what are the events occurred in the page. For example , if a user goes through certain links by clicking , then the clicked elements must be stored in a template format.

Comment: What is this for? Visual UI test automation? What is the template format you expect?

Comment: Template format is just a javascript template, which contains the collection of user actions. The purpose is for administrative purpose. For example an administrator gives access to some site and wants to know the actions of a user performed in that site

Comment: May be some kind of tab Recording